# Django:Map urls to class like in web.py

Tags: python, django, web, web.py

i am learning django but gave web.py a try first. 
while reading django's documentation i found that in i need to check for the request type in each method.. like:

```
def myview():
  if request.method == "POST":
    #blah balh 
    #ke$ha (jst kiddn)
  else:
    #(balh)x2
```

can the web.py type classes be implemented in django like

```
class myView():
 def GET(self):
   #cool
 def POST(self):
   #double cool
```

it would be super cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible with the new (as in Django 1.3) [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/):

```
from django.views.generic.base import View

class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # return a response here

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # return a response here
```

Usually, you don't have to use the `View` base class, there are many views that are geared towards all kinds of cases, e.g. `TemplateView` or `FormView`. Reinout van Rees has two excellent blog posts that go into the details:

http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/08/24/class-based-views-walkthrough.html

http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/08/24/class-based-views-usage.html